# trying to launch a command with runas on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line

here is my command:

```
runas /noprofile /user:Administrateur cmd choco install vlc
```

How to run choco install with runas on windows 10 in command mode?

Comment: Please don't make us guess: what happens when you run this command?

Comment: You probably need to add the Admin credentials in the Runas command.

Answer (score 0):

The account of `Administrator` is disabled by default.
The Runas command will innocently ask for the password of this disabled account
only to reward you with the preordained error message:

> 1326: The user name or password is incorrect.

Do not enable the user account of `Administrator`, as you would be opening a big
security hole.

Give instead the name of another administrator account that is truly
enabled and to which you know the password.